# use Indirect within link path in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a formula in a excel sheet like the one below where B30 -> B33 are variable values and the folder "Salary" must stay on Desktop for it to work.

But when i tried to move folder Salary to another location such as: D:\, then it won't work anymore because the link ref within Indirect did not change accordingly.

```
 =(D6+INDIRECT("'C:\Users\ryan\Desktop\Salary\"&B30&"\"&B31&"\"&B32&"\
["&B33&".xls]salary details'!$D$6"))*$C$15
```

Is there anyway to solve this problem so that I can move folder Salary anywhere I want? For example, I send this folder to my friend computer and he can work on it without the #REF error?

Comment: Did it work when the external workbook was open? Beyond the fact that you may not have permissions to access another user's folder INDIRECT does not work on closed external references; never did.

Comment: You can have the person enter the folder path into a cell and use that cell reference in place of the `'C\Users\ryan\Desktop\` text.

Comment: You are right, the exteral workbook must be opened for it to work. But what i am trying to do is that I want to move the folder "Salary" to another location such as D:\ and the link ref should change accordingly such as this: =(D6+INDIRECT("'D:\Salary\"&B30&"\"&B31&"\"&B32&"\
["&B33&".xls]salary details'!$D$6"))*$C$15

Comment: I can use the C:\Users\ryan\Desktop as varible, but i am trying to automate my work without typo errors like this.

Comment: My suggestion is the best automation you can do considering the requirements. There is no way to create a listener for an Excel cell to be able to change when a folder is moved. If you want to avoid typos, you can implement some VBA with the `Application.GetOpenFilename` method.